# How to print as integer instead of float

Tags: python

The purpose of this program is to print the average and the maximum number of a list of numbers.

Here is the code:

```
num_list = []
total = 0

num_list = [int(num) for num in input().split()]

for ele in range(0, len(num_list)):
    total += num_list[ele]

number_objects = len(num_list)

def average(num_list):
    average = total / number_objects
    return average

average(num_list)

print(average(num_list), max(num_list))
```

The output needs to be printed as a whole number, not a decimal(so no 10.0, just 10). Surely, I am missing something. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: FYI you can use `total = sum(num_list)`

Comment: What happens if the average is 10.5? Should print 10 or 11?